Help place a texture along a slanted edge with a rounded corner
Hello dear Blender community, I am still a complete beginner in Blender and am facing a problem that I urgently need your help with.
I'm currently working on a project where I modeled a workpiece that has a 50 degree beveled edge, with rounded corners.
My goal is to place a plywood wood texture along this edge to create a realistic look. Unfortunately, despite intensive efforts, I have the problem that the plywood strips do not go continuously around the board. Either they are offset or distorted and I just can't find a solution to fix the problem.
I've tried various approaches such as adjusting the UV maps and experimenting with different mapping techniques, but so far with no success. It seems like I'm stuck at one point and just can't move forward.
I would be incredibly grateful if someone with more experience in Blender could give me some advice on how to solve this problem. Maybe there's a specific technique or workflow that I've missed?
If it's helpful, I'm happy to attach a few pictures of the problem so you can get a better idea.


Please excuse my awkwardness, I'm really just at the beginning of my Blender journey and any hint or tip would be extremely helpful.
Thank you in advance for your support!
Kind regards, Max

Hello, is your texture repeatable? Maybe pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

As @moonboots says sharing your Blend file with your images packed into it would be helpful. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
